# Play Console error: The Android App Bundle was not signed, and was also signed with the wrong key

Tags: android, google-play-console

I'm trying to upload an AAB to the Google Play console, and need to use an upload key that matches what Google Play is expecting.

I used Android Studio to generate a new keystore for me (`myapp.jks`). It asked me for all the Domain Name (DN; OU, etc.) information and I assume its using OpenSSL to generate a self-signed cert under the hood (?).

When I use `keytool` to inspect the key inside this JKS (after Android Studio has generated it) I see that its fingerprint begins with `1F`. So far, so good.

I then sign my AAB with this Keystore file and attempt to upload it to my prepared release. When I do so I get an error:

[image]

Its expecting a key signed with a SHA1 fingerprint starting with `85`, but sees (correctly) that my AAB was signed with a SH1 fingerprint beginning with `1F`. Sure enough, if I go to the `Setup >> App Signing` menu, I see that the upload key certificate that Google Play is expecting has a fingerprint that starts with `85`.

So I'm presenting a key with a SHA1 fingerprint beginning with `1F`, which is the JKS that Android Studio created for me.

But my Google Play app account is expecting a "certificate" with a SHA1 fingerprint beginning with `85`.

I see a "Download Certificate" link on this App Signing screen, but that only downloads the *upload certificate*, not the *upload key*.

**So how the heck do I get my hands on the upload key (beginning with SHA1 fingerprint `85`) so that I can sign my AAB with it and have it be accepted by Google Play?!**

Comment: You need to generate APK from relase mode rather debug mode to upload to play store. Which you can generate From Android Studio Build -> Generate Signed Bundle/APk -> Select APK and Select Or Create A Key and Select Release Mode and generate apk and upload it

Comment: Yes, so basically it's not Google who's securing you app. It's you who should sign the app beforehand with your own keystore, and then Google will add an extra layer of security by adding their signature.

Comment: @ChiragThummar Nope, google does not recommend that process anymore (and in fact it doesn't even allow it for new apps anymore).

Comment: You won't find the private key anywhere to download, because that would be a major security risk. The simplest is probably to follow google's instructions on resetting the upload key https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#reset_upload_key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand from the documentation, to sign your Android App Bundle (AAB) and upload it to the Google Play Console should be a five steps process:

**Step 1: Create an Upload Key**
You need to create an upload key, which is different from the app signing key that Google manages. According to the [Google Play Console Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en) page, you should:

- Create an upload key following the instructions provided.
- Sign your app bundle with this upload key.

The upload key is used to authenticate the initial upload of the app to Google Play.

**Step 2: Sign Your App Bundle**
Before uploading to Google Play, you need to sign your AAB with your upload key. The [Android Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle) explains that you should build signed Android App Bundles using Android Studio or the command line.

**Step 3: Register Your Upload Key with Google Play**
If this is your first time uploading an app, or if you have generated a new upload key, you need to register it with Google Play. On the [Google Play Console Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en) page, it is detailed under "Step 3: Register your app signing key with API providers". That step is very important because Google has to recognize the upload key to authenticate your uploads.

**Step 4: Prepare and Roll Out Your Release**
Follow the instructions to prepare and roll out your release on Google Play. As you upload your signed AAB, Google Play will then take care of re-signing your app with the app signing key managed by Google. That is highlighted in the [Google Play Console Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en) under "Set up and manage Play App Signing".

**Step 5: Understand Google Play's Role**
As per the [Android Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle), Google Play uses your uploaded AAB to generate and serve optimized APKs for each device configuration. That means that while Google Play manages the final signing and distribution, you are responsible for the initial app bundle signing with your upload key.

---

The errors you see suggest a mismatch between the key you are using to sign your AAB and the upload key registered with Google Play.
Make sure you are using the correct upload key that you have registered. If you have lost your upload key or if it has been compromised, follow the "Lost or compromised upload key?" section from the [Google Play Console Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en) to reset it.

You do have to sign your AAB with an upload key that you manage, then upload it to Google Play, where Google will manage the app signing key and use it for the final signing of your app. That two-step signing process participates in the security and integrity of your app on the Play Store.

---

From the comments:

> So could I use an OpenSSL (self signed) certificate, add it to a JKS, sign my app with the JKS/self-signed-cert, and then upload the AAB? Because if so, I tried that, at which point the error I get is: Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. It's like Google wants to "have its cake and eat it too", but it can't, the Laws of Nature strictly forbid any mortal organism such a boon

Regarding the use of an OpenSSL (self-signed) certificate, this is addressed in **Step 1: Create an Upload Key** and **Step 3: Register Your Upload Key with Google Play**.

**Step 1: Create an Upload Key**:

While technically possible to use an OpenSSL self-signed certificate to create a Java Keystore (JKS), this is not the standard practice nor is it recommended for Android app signing. The standard practice, as outlined in the [Google Play Console Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en) documentation, is to create a new upload key using the `keytool` utility, which is part of the Java Development Kit (JDK). That upload key is then used to sign your app bundle before uploading to Google Play.

**Step 3: Register Your Upload Key with Google Play**:
Once you have created your upload key, you must register it with Google Play as detailed on the same [Google Play Console Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en) page. That is a critical step because if you sign your app with a key that Google Play does not recognize (e.g., an OpenSSL self-signed certificate not registered as the upload key), you will receive an error message indicating that the app bundle is signed with the wrong key.

To resolve your error, make sure the key you are using to sign the AAB is indeed the upload key that you have registered with Google Play. If you attempt to sign the AAB with any other key, even if it is a valid JKS, Google Play will reject it because it does not match the registered upload key that Google has on record for your app.

So, the "cake" here is the security provided by having a known and registered key sign the app bundle before Google adds another layer of security by re-signing it with the app signing key.
Google Play's requirement for the upload key to be registered makes sure the initial upload comes from an authenticated source, which helps for maintaining the chain of trust in app distribution.

---

> So how the heck do I get my hands on the upload key (beginning with SHA1 fingerprint `85`) so that I can sign my AAB with it and have it be accepted by Google Play?!

You have created a new keystore via Android Studio, which is presumably for signing your app. When you inspected this keystore using the `keytool` command, you noticed that the SHA1 fingerprint of the key inside this keystore begins with `1F`. That new keystore is meant to provide the upload key for signing your Android App Bundle (AAB).

However, when you attempted to upload your signed AAB to Google Play, you received an error. The Google Play Console is indicating that it expects an upload key with a SHA1 fingerprint starting with `85`, not `1F`. That mismatch is why you get the error.

The Google Play Console is essentially saying, "I recognize an upload key with a SHA1 fingerprint starting with `85`, but you are presenting me with a key that has a SHA1 fingerprint starting with `1F`."

That means that at some point, an upload key was generated, registered with Google Play, and its fingerprint begins with `85`. That is the key that Google Play expects you to use for signing your AAB. However, the keystore you have created (and are using) does not contain this key; instead, it contains a new key with a different SHA1 fingerprint (`1F`).

The "Download Certificate" link on the App Signing page in the Google Play Console allows you to download the public certificate associated with the expected upload key (the one starting with `85`). That certificate can be used for various verification purposes but does not include the private key necessary for signing your app.

To resolve this, you need to find the original keystore that contains the upload key with the SHA1 fingerprint starting with `85` and use that to sign your app.

If you cannot find this original keystore, you will need to contact Google Play Developer Support to reset your upload key. That would mean generating a new upload key using the `keytool` utility. And create a new keystore and key pair with the `keytool` command.

```bash
keytool -genkeypair -v -keystore new-upload-keystore.jks -alias new-upload -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Contact Google Play Developer Support and follow their process to reset the upload key. Once the new upload key is registered by Google, use this key to sign your AABs moving forward.

And to sign the AAB with this new keystore:

```bash
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA-256 -keystore new-upload-keystore.jks app-release.aab new-upload
```

---

I'm trying to track down the missing Upload Key, but will likely have to embark on the ["reset request" process](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#reset_upload_key). There's one other developer who may have generated it, but they are on vacation through the end of the year. Meanwhile, can you please verify that my understanding of the process is correct?

> I **believe** I need to:
>
> 1. find or reset the Upload Key, which will be a PEM and CER file pair. The CER file will have an SHA-1 fingerprint that I'll be able to see on the *App signing* page.
> 2. Then I sign my AAB (at build-time) with a JKS containing the PEM file (that I'll add via `keytool`). Which *should* (theoretically) allow me to
> 3. Upload the signed AAB to my Closed Track release.

True, except your upload key will actually be a [Java Keystore (JKS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_KeyStore) file, not PEM and CER files. If you cannot find the original JKS file, you will indeed need to go through the [reset request process](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#reset_upload_key) with Google Play. Once reset, Google Play will expect the new upload key for all future uploads.

You sign your AAB with the private key that is inside the JKS. The signing process does not directly involve a PEM file. The JKS is a binary keystore format used by Java, which contains your private key and public certificate. The `keytool` command can be used to inspect, export, import, and manage entries within this keystore. You use the `jarsigner` tool or Android Studio to sign the AAB with the JKS (possibly, the [KeyStore Explorer](http://keystore-explorer.org/) works too).
The SHA-1 fingerprint of the public certificate inside this JKS should match the one displayed on the Google Play Console's *App signing* page.

After signing your AAB with the JKS containing your upload key, you can upload it to the Google Play Console for your Closed Track release.

Upload the signed AAB to Google Play Console for your Closed Track release. If the AAB is signed with the correct upload key, the Google Play Console will accept it and proceed with the release process.

Comment: Thanks @VonC (+1), so after reading your answer, I have pinpointed my problem to the upload key. Please see my edits (they are fairly substantial, but now clearly reflect the root of the problem). Basically, my understanding is that I need to sign my AAB with an upload key whose SHA1 fingerprints match the upload certificate expected by Google Play, and I just need help finding the Upload Key. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you again, I'm trying to track down the missing Upload Key but will likely have to embark on the "reset request" process. There's one other developer that may have generated it but they are on vacation through the end of the year. In the mean time, can you please verify that my understanding of the process is correct?

Comment: I **believe** I need to: (1) find or reset the Upload Key which will be a PEM and CER file pair. The CER file will have a SHA-1 fingerprint that I'll be able to see on the _App signing_ page. (2) Then I sign my AAB (at build-time) with a JKS containing the PEM file (that I'll add via `keytool`). Which _should_ (theoretically) allow me to (3) Upload the signed AAB to my Closed Track release. Is my understanding here correct? Thanks so much for all the help thus far, its been frustrating but you have been amazing!

Comment: Well, if you have another colleague that may have generated that key, it's definitely worth contacting him, because if you know reset the key, he won't be able to upload anymore with his key (unless you share the new key with him). But yes in principle you are right, you need the private key for the certificate which is registered in the PlayStore to be able to upload an AAB. And resetting that upload key won't have any negative impact on your released version, because the PlayStore is still using the same app signing key for your releases...

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup I have edited the answer to address your comments. See also [derpirscher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776927/derpirscher)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77699756/play-console-error-the-android-app-bundle-was-not-signed-and-was-also-signed-w/77709121#comment137031214_77709121).

Comment: Thanks @derpirscher but if I find out that this colleague generated an upload key and didn't share it with the rest of the team, and because of that, she hamstrung development for 2 1/2 weeks, I'm going to fire her when she gets back.